# Specify host to a database running on a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a .Net app that connects to the PostgreSQL database. The .Net app is running directly on my machine and the PostgreSQL is running in a docker container on my machine.

The docker-compose section that brings up Postgres is:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db_in_docker:
    image: postgres
    container_name: mydb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    volumes:
      - local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

To connect to this database from .Net app, I specify a connection string:

```
"HOST = localhost; PORT = 5432; DATABASE = 'testdb'; PASSWORD = 'test'; USER ID = 'test'"
```

Here the host is set to `localhost`. This works because my machine is the host and I can forward 5432 to the container's port 5432.

However, when both the .NET app and database are running in separate containers, this doesn't work. In that case, I have to specify the name of the service that is in the docker-compose file and update the connection string to `HOST = db_in_docker`

Question: Is it possible to assign a host for the database connection that will work locally as well as inside a docker container?

Comment: Other environments like, for example, Amazon's hosted Relational Database Service (RDS) will have different hostnames again; there is no single hostname that will reach "the database" in all environments.  You might make this configurable through an environment variable.

Comment: @DavidMaze  Yes, the connection will be different for a different environment. In this case, the host is different if both apps are running in docker vs just the db running in docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze Maybe an alias is the way? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases

Comment: I don't think you can use that to make another container be `localhost`; and if the single host name isn't `localhost` then you'd have to also tweak the host's `/etc/hosts` file to match, which will always be a fragile setup.  `environment: [PGHOST=database]` in a Compose setup seems easier.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `hostname`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db_in_docker:
    hostname: db_in_docker
    image: postgres
    container_name: mydb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    volumes:
      - local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Also, your containers should use the same network.

Comment: Setting `hostname:` for a container does almost nothing; it might be visible if you get a debugging shell in the container but that's about the only effect.  It has no effect at all on connections between containers or on connections from the host.